# python subprocess behaviour changed between ubuntu 20 and 22?

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04

I upgraded my ubuntu installation to 22.04 from 18.04 yesterday. Now I notice that python virtual environment is no longer working as expect.

I use python to run a lot of tools, and hence am highly dependent on subprocess library.

However to my "horror"  I notice that it changed quite a lot, even when I keep using python 3.8. Mostly I notice I can no longer interact and the output is no longer piped to the shell that executes the python script.

```
import subprocess


def main():
    proc = subprocess.run(["echo", "test"], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print('-------')
    print(proc.stdout)
    print("FINISH")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I call this with `python3.8 test.py` I notice that the output isn't displayed in the shell. However it is displayed when the prints happen.

What changed and how do I fix this? So output of the subprocess is piped to the output and can be seen?

Especially since a lot of tools are just running dockers (which in turn run git/javascript programs) and having output while the process is busy is kind of useful.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what is wrong with this demo? My suspicion is that you are actually complaining about the output from `docker` which was changed in recent versions. You can get (something like) the old behavior with `docker ... --progress=plain`

Comment: Like I said the output from the subprocess (output of echo test - which should show `echo`) is never displayed to the console. As if `subprocess.PIPE` isn't there.

Comment: Er, you mean `test`?